# If any two events are eventually independent under iteration, then the measure is trivial

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Given a measure-preserving system $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu,T)$ with the property that for any $A,B\in\mathcal{B}$, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n>N$:

$$\mu(A\cap T^{-n}B)=\mu(A)\mu(B)
$$

Then $\mu$ is trivial in the sense that for each $A\in\mathcal{B}$, $\mu(A)=0$ or $1$

I'm having trouble showing this is true. I know that if $(X,T)$ has such a property then it is ergodic, but I'm not able to show that the measure must be trivial.

Comment: Since there is no answer yet, and this is nowhere near my expertise, all I can do is provide suggestions which might or might not help. For example, since you know that the system is Ergodic, do you think its possible to show that $T(A)\subset A$ for all $A\in\mathcal{B}$? If that were the case, then you are done (although so far, I have not seen any reason for this to be true). On the other hand, I have a strong feeling that the converse Borel-Cantelli lemma will come into play at some point. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a hard question! It took me a long time. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909000/events-in-a-measure-preserving-system-satisfying-mu-a-cap-t-nb-mua/3346301#3346301)

Comment: @UserA see above comment